# Crash dump collection and Performance Impact

Tags: windows, performance, debugging, memory-dump

Currently, I am searching for a solution that would allow me to monitor a .NET Windows Service Application, in the production environment, and collect memory dumps. I'd like to collect them based on some specific thresholds, at will and on application crashes. I am aware of various methods to achieve this, such as:

1. DebugDiag
2. Procdump
3. Through WER
4. ADPlus
5. WinDbg etc.

Some of the methods facilitate the collection during a crash, such as option #3, while others can trigger based on performance counters, such as #1 and #2. Any non-invasive debugger can help me achieve the collection, but I am not sure what's the **performance impact** of having one attached. For example, if I use Procdump with the -e switch to collect memory dumps on unhandled exceptions, what would be the overhead for the monitored application? Bear in mind that I am referring to a production environment.

I'd be grateful if I you could point me a source or method that explains the performance impact of attaching a non-invasive debugger for memory dump collection. Ideally, that'd be a **quantitative measure**, although it exceeds my expectations.

P.S: I am not referring to the time needed for the memory dump to be written in the disk, where the application is completely frozen. That's another thing.

Comment: You should be using AppDomain.UnhandledException first, minidumps are a desperation solution for managed code.  Perf impact should otherwise be zero, ProcDump acts like a just-in-time debugger when you ask it to monitor for unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Yes, the AppDomain.UnhandledException is already being used, but there are various OutOfMemory exceptions that have caused various crash incidents in the past. Some of them have been dealt with successfully by collecting memory dumps - others persist. It's even more annoying seeing that the sporadic incidents seem to have different root causes.

Comment: In the case of an unhandled exception, the performance impact isn't hugely relevant as the process is about to shut down anyway. Restarting the application may be delayed due to this but other than that I don't see how the impact is important.